# Get biggest node from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, max, scenekit, arkit

I have an array of SCNNodes and I need to identify which one of them has the highest width.

I know how to calculate the width, but not how to compare among all nodes within the array and return the one with the highest value.

Here’s a sample code:

```
var walls = [SCNNode]()
   
For wall in walls  {
    let wallWidth = (wall.boundingBox.max.x-wall.boundingBox.min.x)
    print(wallWidth)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the max function of array.

```
var walls = [SCNNode]()
let maxNode = walls.max { (left, right) -> Bool in
    let leftWidth = (left.boundingBox.max.x-left.boundingBox.min.x)
    let rightWidth = (right.boundingBox.max.x-right.boundingBox.min.x)
    return leftWidth < rightWidth
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raja! That's exactly what I needed.